# How to set an objects rect to a shapes rect while they're touching in pygame without permanently setting this as the objects coordinates?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been writing a frogger like game and am attempting to set the coordinates of the player avatar to that of the item they land on. I'm trying to figure out how to set the avatar's centerx to be the centerx of the item moving across the screen in which they attempt to land on. How would I do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen_height = 750
screen_width = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Frogger")
FPS = 200

player = pygame.image.load('frog.bmp')
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_rect.left = 300 + 11
player_rect.top = screen_height - 68

#For player movement
up_movements = 0
down_movements = 0
left_movements = 0 
right_movements = 0
up_movement = False
down_movement = False
left_movement = False
right_movement = False

x_logs = [1, 301, 601]
y_logs = [74,149,224, 299, 374, 449, 524, 599] 
log_width = 74
log_height = 74
logs_created = []

class Log():

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction
        self.log = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),(self.x, self.y, log_width, log_height))

    def move_log(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            self.x += 5
            self.log.right += 5
        if self.direction == 'left':
            self.x -= 5
            self.log.right -= 5

    def draw_log(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),(self.x, self.y, log_width, log_height))


    def delete_log(self, item):
        logs_created.remove(item)

    def draw_new_logs(self): # To address the issue of infinitely spawning in logs, put the if statements in the main game loop and only have it run this method if it meets the requirements
        if self.direction == 'right':
            if self.log.right > screen_width:
                logs_created.append(Log(-73, self.y, 'right'))
        if self.direction == 'left':
            if self.log.left < 0:
                logs_created.append(Log(screen_width - 1, self.y, 'left'))

for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        if (y_logs.index(y) % 2) == 0: 
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'left'))
        else:
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right')) 


while True:
    screen.fill((0, 119, 190))
    starting_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0, 675, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    finish_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0,0, screen_width, screen_height / 10))


    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    for log in logs_created:
        log.draw_log()
        log.move_log()

        log.draw_new_logs()

        if log.direction == 'right':
            if log.log.right > screen_width:
                log.delete_log(log)
        if log.direction == 'left':
            if log.log.left < 0:
                log.delete_log(log)

        elif player_rect.colliderect(log.log):
            player.get_rect().center = (log.log.centerx, log.log.centery)
            if log.direction == 'right':
                player_rect.x += 5
            if log.direction == 'left':
                player_rect.x -= 5
        elif player_rect.colliderect(starting_area) or player_rect.colliderect(finish_area):
            pass
        else:
            '''player_rect.left = 300 + 11
            player_rect.top = screen_height - 68'''




    screen.blit(player, player_rect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                down_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                left_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right_movement = True

        #Movements
    if up_movement == True:
        if player_rect.top > 11:
            if up_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y -= 15
                up_movements += 15
            else:
                up_movements = 0
                up_movement = False
        else:
            up_movement = False
            up_movements = 0
    if down_movement == True:
        if player_rect.bottom <= screen_height - 11:
            if down_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y += 15
                down_movements += 15
            else:
                down_movements = 0
                down_movement = False
        else:
            down_movement = False
            down_movements = 0

    if left_movement == True:
        if player_rect.left > 11:
            if left_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x -= 15
                left_movements += 15
                print(player_rect.left)
            else:
                left_movements = 0
                left_movement = False
    if right_movement == True:
        if player_rect.right <= screen_width - 11:
            if right_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x += 15
                right_movements += 15
            else:
                right_movements = 0
                right_movement = False

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the log class, `self.log = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),(self.x, self.y, log_width, log_height))` This is used for drawing, you want the rect of it. So chnage it to `self.log = pygame.Rect(x, y, log_width, log_height)`. This means you dont need a `self.x` and `self.y`. you can use the rect.

```
def move_log(self):
    if self.direction == 'right':
        self.log.x += 5
    if self.direction == 'left':
        self.log.x -= 5
```

then for moving the player on the logs. You were close. you had an `elif collision` which meant if it wasn't moving left, check for collision which is why the right worked and not the left.So change it to `if` Lastly you were getting the rect of the player with `player.get_rect().center = (log.log.centerx, log.log.centery)`. This creates a new rect with no x and no y. So change it to the rect you do have `player_rect.centerx = log.log.centerx`

Here is all the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen_height = 750
screen_width = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Frogger")
FPS = 200

player = pygame.image.load('frog.bmp')
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_rect.left = 300 + 11
player_rect.top = screen_height - 68

#For player movement
up_movements = 0
down_movements = 0
left_movements = 0 
right_movements = 0
up_movement = False
down_movement = False
left_movement = False
right_movement = False

x_logs = [1, 301, 601]
y_logs = [74,149,224, 299, 374, 449, 524, 599] 
log_width = 74
log_height = 74
logs_created = []

class Log():

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.direction = direction
        self.log = pygame.Rect(x, y, log_width, log_height)

    def move_log(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            self.log.x += 5
        if self.direction == 'left':
            self.log.x -= 5

    def draw_log(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0),self.log)


    def delete_log(self, item):
        logs_created.remove(item)

    def draw_new_logs(self): # To address the issue of infinitely spawning in logs, put the if statements in the main game loop and only have it run this method if it meets the requirements
        if self.direction == 'right':
            if self.log.left > screen_width:
                logs_created.append(Log(-73, self.log.y, 'right'))
        if self.direction == 'left':
            if self.log.right < 0:
                logs_created.append(Log(screen_width - 1, self.log.y, 'left'))

for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        if (y_logs.index(y) % 2) == 0: 
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'left'))
        else:
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right')) 


while True:
    screen.fill((0, 119, 190))
    starting_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0, 675, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    finish_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0,0, screen_width, screen_height / 10))


    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    for log in logs_created:
        log.draw_log()
        log.move_log()


        log.draw_new_logs()

        if log.direction == 'right':
            if log.log.left > screen_width:
                log.delete_log(log)
        if log.direction == 'left':
            if log.log.right < 0:
                log.delete_log(log)

        if player_rect.colliderect(log.log):
            player_rect.centerx = log.log.centerx
        elif player_rect.colliderect(starting_area) or player_rect.colliderect(finish_area):
            pass
        else:
            '''player_rect.left = 300 + 11
            player_rect.top = screen_height - 68'''




    screen.blit(player, player_rect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                down_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                left_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right_movement = True

        #Movements
    if up_movement == True:
        if player_rect.top > 11:
            if up_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y -= 15
                up_movements += 15
            else:
                up_movements = 0
                up_movement = False
        else:
            up_movement = False
            up_movements = 0
    if down_movement == True:
        if player_rect.bottom <= screen_height - 11:
            if down_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y += 15
                down_movements += 15
            else:
                down_movements = 0
                down_movement = False
        else:
            down_movement = False
            down_movements = 0

    if left_movement == True:
        if player_rect.left > 11:
            if left_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x -= 15
                left_movements += 15
                print(player_rect)
            else:
                left_movements = 0
                left_movement = False
    if right_movement == True:
        if player_rect.right <= screen_width - 11:
            if right_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x += 15
                right_movements += 15
            else:
                right_movements = 0
                right_movement = False

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain to me why my else statement in the for loop ```for log in logs_created:``` returns True even when it appears that the player is not in contact with the ocean? I'm trying to use this as a restart mechanism if the player lands in the water.

Comment: @GalacticAvenger It is because your checking for a collision against every log, so it is going to say your in the ocean for every log except the one your on. Just create a bool and set it to False before the the logloop and then set it to True if it collides with starting area or log, then after log loop, check if its False, if it is, then your in ocean